# How to identify the currently available wireless networks with Python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, wireless, ssid

Is there a way to get a list of wireless networks (SSID's) that are currently available? And seeing what is the current connected network?

Doesn't need to be exactly the SSID, I just need to identify the current wireless network.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the netsh command. I don't remember the exact syntax used to invoke cli commands from within python, but I'm sure it should be fairly easy to locate.

The article below has more information about how to use netsh itself:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28WS.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanShowNetworks

Comment: netsh can't list wireless networks on Windows XP, only on Vista and 7.